# Creating leaderboard

Tags: ios, leaderboard

I want to create an app that will have **my own** `tableView` of the top (public) high scores. Basically a leaderboard. I don't want to have the typical look:

[image]

I want to customize it. Is there a way I can create it myself? If not, is there a library that is already made?

**Update**

Basically I want to create my own leaderboard from scratch, if that's possible. How can I get data from the web every time a new high score gets uploaded? (It will be constantly updating!)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to customize the tableView. There are ways by which you can create custom table view with custom rows. You need to create custom cells either by code or by Xibs or in Storyboards, as per you design.
Below links will guide you 
[Customize tableView](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

[Custom Cell using Xibs](https://medium.com/@musawiralishah/creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-nib-xib-files-in-xcode-9bee5824e722)

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know how to customize tableViewsCells. My question is how to add the score data to my own tableView. I do prefer creating my own from scratch, if that's possible. The steps would be to upload scores online. Then in the app, I would have to constantly check online for the highest score. If that's possible, I'd really appreciate someone showing me basically how to do it. If not, then I can use apples leaderboard, but I would want to insert the data in my own tableView